# How to call a function inside the div React Component jsx

Tags: reactjs

This is the Component constructor and I've already bind the function checkActive which compares the props from parent component with the argument.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.checkActive = this.checkActive.bind(this);
  }

  checkActive(option) {
    if (this.props.active === option) {
      return 'active';
    }
  }
```

I would like to render 'active' to one of my div. So I start with:

```
<div {this.checkActive('meet')}>
```

I want to render it to : `<div active>`

The error shows: **Unexpected token, expected ...**

Did I make the function wrong or we cannot pass the function inside the div?

Comment: `active` is not a valid HTML attribute. And no, JSX doesn't allow to set props this way. There are other ways, but it seems weird that you want to set an invalid HTML attribute. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @FelixKling I just want to active the content that shows user know where they are. I use styled-components library.

Comment: But `active` is still not a valid HTML attribute. Do you want to set the **CSS class** `active` by any chance? I.e. `<div class="active">` ?

Comment: @FelixKling I've tried it and it works fine. However, I want to hold the structure so I was trying to make it work. Thank you very much for your support. I think I should use css class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div active={this.props.active === "meet" ? "true" : void 0} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `className` to active component below in your `div`

```
<div className={this.props.active === "meet" ? "active" : ""} />
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can try it by this way

```
 <div className={this.props.active == "meet"?"active":""} />
```